# Обфускация модуля

Tags: android, компиляция, декомпиляция, интерпретатор

Собственно, вопрос: есть ли программное решение для обфускации отдельно модуля, аля dex файла?

Comment: proguard вам в помощь

Comment: Обработку proguard'ом тяжело назвать действительно обфускацией. Интересует, что-то вроде dexProtector

Comment: И, конечно же, бесплатное?

Comment: @bukkojot
Нет, все равно - платное или бесплатное, главное - результат

Comment: Тогда почему не декс-протектор?

Comment: @bukkojot , На сколько я знаю, там нет обфускации чисто dex файла. А если обрабатывать апк и после вынимать от туда dex модуль, то потом не запустишь, тк теряются EntryPoint. Т.е. мне надо обфусцировать динамически подгружаемый модуль(dex) файла, но в дексе такого нет

Comment: Энтри-поинты прописаны в Манифесте, так что можешь разобрать манифест и перепрописать.

Comment: @bukkojot ,вы меня видимо в общем плане не понимаете) У меня есть приложение (апк), сам по себе он лишь "загрузчик". У меня есть вот 10 модулей, аля "чистых" dex файлов. По необходимости, мое приложение подгружает нужный мне модуль через функцию DexLoader. Те мне нужно обфусцировать именно этот голый dex, а DexProtector этого не умеет, умеет он только aar/apk обрабатывать. Вот в чем трабла.

Comment: @Magic вам в таком случае подойдет либо пакер, либо протектор, а не просто обфускатор. Вы можете легко нагуглить отличие и примеры использования. А вообще, люди которые захотят узнать что у вас в кишках программы - все узнают.

Comment: @Lex Hobbit , не сочтите за лень, но можете ли вы что-то конкретное посоветовать?